# python heroku push rejected after installing SQLIte3

Tags: python, git, heroku

im trying to put my discord bot on heroku but its not working any help?
my python is 3.6.9

```
Enumerating objects: 17, done.
Counting objects: 100% (17/17), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects: 100% (17/17), 3.01 KiB | 440.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 17 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.9
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to scumbotfin.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/scumbotfin.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/scumbotfin.git'
```

my requirement file is...

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
dnspython==1.16.0
PyNaCl==1.3.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a git repository with two files : `hello.py` and `requirements.txt`(as mentioned in the question). Created a new heroku app and the push was successful. Maybe its the problem with your application, have you tried running it locally ?

You can run the app locally before deploying it on heroku using this cli command `heroku local` provided you have setup a proc file for your app. You can read more about running python apps locally using heroku [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python?singlepage=true#run-the-app-locally)

**Log**

```
C:\..> git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 376 bytes | 62.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.9
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: Sqlite3 successfully installed.
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py (from -r /tmp/build_63599c46828573310e42158a6ad29f79/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Cloning https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py to /tmp/pip-ucn6oyti-build
remote:        Collecting dnspython==1.16.0 (from -r /tmp/build_63599c46828573310e42158a6ad29f79/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/d3/3aa0e7213ef72b8585747aa0e271a9523e713813b9a20177ebe1e939deb0/dnspython-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (188kB)
remote:        Collecting PyNaCl==1.3.0 (from -r /tmp/build_63599c46828573310e42158a6ad29f79/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/15/2cd0a203f318c2240b42cd9dd13c931ddd61067809fee3479f44f086103e/PyNaCl-1.3.0-cp34-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (759kB)
remote:        Collecting async-timeout==3.0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_63599c46828573310e42158a6ad29f79/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/1e/5a4441be21b0726c4464f3f23c8b19628372f606755a9d2e46c187e65ec4/async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0 (from discord.py==1.3.0a2151+gc62b6c3->-r /tmp/build_63599c46828573310e42158a6ad29f79/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/39/7eb5f98d24904e0f6d3edb505d4aa60e3ef83c0a58d6fe18244a51757247/aiohttp-3.6.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.2MB)
remote:        Collecting websockets<7.0,>=6.0 (from discord.py==1.3.0a2151+gc62b6c3->-r /tmp/build_63599c46828573310e42158a6ad29f79/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/fe/99aeaf97985585baefca8d56125ec828ef5549276324ec319b63a4da686d/websockets-6.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (88kB)
remote:        Collecting cffi>=1.4.1 (from PyNaCl==1.3.0->-r /tmp/build_63599c46828573310e42158a6ad29f79/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/49/72/0d42f94fe94afa8030350c26e9d787219f3f008ec9bf6b86c66532b29236/cffi-1.13.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (397kB)
remote:        Collecting six (from PyNaCl==1.3.0->-r /tmp/build_63599c46828573310e42158a6ad29f79/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/26/32b8464df2a97e6dd1b656ed26b2c194606c16fe163c695a992b36c11cdf/six-1.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.5; python_version < "3.7" (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py==1.3.0a2151+gc62b6c3->-r /tmp/build_63599c46828573310e42158a6ad29f79/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/92/705fe8aca27678e01bbdd7738173b8e7df0088a2202c80352f664630d638/typing_extensions-3.7.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting idna-ssl>=1.0; python_version < "3.7" (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py==1.3.0a2151+gc62b6c3->-r /tmp/build_63599c46828573310e42158a6ad29f79/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/46/03/07c4894aae38b0de52b52586b24bf189bb83e4ddabfe2e2c8f2419eec6f4/idna-ssl-1.1.0.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0 (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py==1.3.0a2151+gc62b6c3->-r /tmp/build_63599c46828573310e42158a6ad29f79/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/82/53cada22e60638a036847b198282109d82b7afd309d6d76c754219b79fad/yarl-1.4.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (252kB)
remote:        Collecting chardet<4.0,>=2.0 (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py==1.3.0a2151+gc62b6c3->-r /tmp/build_63599c46828573310e42158a6ad29f79/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
remote:        Collecting attrs>=17.3.0 (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py==1.3.0a2151+gc62b6c3->-r /tmp/build_63599c46828573310e42158a6ad29f79/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/db/4313ab3be961f7a763066401fb77f7748373b6094076ae2bda2806988af6/attrs-19.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting multidict<5.0,>=4.5 (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py==1.3.0a2151+gc62b6c3->-r /tmp/build_63599c46828573310e42158a6ad29f79/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/cf/73e67511d9cd60b1d11eab9361c949a209bbb9c742f2ccf59e5e8cd1d686/multidict-4.6.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (348kB)
remote:        Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.4.1->PyNaCl==1.3.0->-r /tmp/build_63599c46828573310e42158a6ad29f79/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/9e/49196946aee219aead1290e00d1e7fdeab8567783e83e1b9ab5585e6206a/pycparser-2.19.tar.gz (158kB)
remote:        Collecting idna>=2.0 (from idna-ssl>=1.0; python_version < "3.7"->aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py==1.3.0a2151+gc62b6c3->-r /tmp/build_63599c46828573310e42158a6ad29f79/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
remote:        Installing collected packages: dnspython, pycparser, cffi, six, PyNaCl, async-timeout, typing-extensions, idna, idna-ssl, multidict, yarl, chardet, attrs, aiohttp, websockets, discord.py
remote:          Running setup.py install for pycparser: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for pycparser: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for idna-ssl: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for idna-ssl: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for discord.py: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for discord.py: finished with status 'done'
remote:        Successfully installed PyNaCl-1.3.0 aiohttp-3.6.2 async-timeout-3.0.1 attrs-19.3.0 cffi-1.13.2 chardet-3.0.4 discord.py-1.3.0a2151+gc62b6c3 dnspython-1.16.0 idna-2.8 idna-ssl-1.1.0 multidict-4.6.1 pycparser-2.19 six-1.13.0 typing-extensions-3.7.4.1 websockets-6.0 yarl-1.4.1
remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 48.8M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v3
remote:        https://cryptic-castle-*****.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/cryptic-castle-*****.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```